# Unrecognized selector sent to custom UIStoryboardSegue instance on ios8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, uistoryboardsegue

I am using a custom segue in Swift (simplified):

```
import Foundation

public class CustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
  override public func perform() {
    super.perform()
  }
}
```

Setting this class as the segue class at the storyboard causing runtime error on IOS 8 while running perfectly on iOS 9:

> **[APP_NAME.CustomSegue setUseDefaultModalPresentationStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

I am using *Present Modally* although getting similar errors when using any other segues type.

Comment: Type should be Custom.

Comment: Thanks! You right that now I am not getting this error. The thing is, I do want that segue to be Modally with Presentation = "Over Current Context".

Comment: @u54r saved my life. You should answer this question and he should mark as accepted.